# Script to get all file names in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, file, directory

I need to get all file names for a directory

```
for file in "$1"/*;do
    echo $file
done
```

gives me `directory_name/file1_name`, `directory_name/file2_name`.
However, I just want the `file1_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion to get only the filename before printing as follows:

```
    for file in "$1"/*;do
        file="${file##*/}"
        echo $file
    done
```

You can find more about parameter expansion over here : [Shell Parameter Expansion (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#:%7E:text=Bash%20uses%20the%20value%20formed,is%20known%20as%20indirect%20expansion%20.)